# Visual Studio .Net Core tag helpers are not working

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, tag-helpers

Well, lets get down to it. I'm using Visual Studio 2015 and ASP.NET core tag helpers have completely stopped working, no idea why as I've not changed anything. I was in work one day, they worked fine, then I came in the next day and now no ASP.NET core web project at all shows any tag helpers!?! I've tried creating a fresh new ASP.NET Core MVC project and they don't work there either!!! I'm completely stuck, is there some setting somewhere that completely turns them off in Visual Studio?

Note that I've checked everything that usually causes this problem according to most other posts. My _ViewImports has the line:-

```
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
```

and here is a complete project.json file from a fresh project I just created and made NO changes to at all:-

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0"
  },

  "tools": {
    "BundlerMinifier.Core": "2.0.238",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "net452": { }
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "**/*.cshtml",
      "appsettings.json",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "prepublish": [ "bower install", "dotnet bundle" ],
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  }
}
```

Also, all the _Layout views and other views have completely lost their highlighting that used to appear. No one else I've found on the internet so far seems to be having this problem, don't suppose anyone else has any ideas?

EDIT:

One of the answers below has solved this for new projects in a new solution but I'm still having problems with existing solutions/projects. Here's the project file contents from one of these existing projects, hopefully someone can spot something here...

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "BundlerMinifier.Core": "2.2.306",
    "Configuration.Web": "1.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.1.0"
  },

  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools":  "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "net452": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Aristotle.Service": {
          "target": "project"
        },
        "Infrastructure": {
          "target": "project"
        }
      }
    }
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "**/*.cshtml",
      "appsettings.json",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "prepublish": [ "bower install", "dotnet bundle" ],
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  }
}
```

I've updated all packages using NuGet to latest versions...

Comment: I have found when I run into similar problems with .net core that updated my packages helps.  It looks like you have a few packages that, even for 452 are at version 1.1.  Maybe upgrade them in that test proj you created and see if it helps.

Comment: Update your project dependencies to latest stable release.

Comment: hi, thanks for the response, I've tried updating all packages to latest version and that has no effect unfortunately. However, creating a new project from scratch now works if I put the tag helper reference in (see other answer below). This doesn't work with all my existing projects however...

Answer (score 46):

I've finally fixed this, but have no idea why the fixed works or why it stopped working in the first place but...

in _ViewImports the line which is:-

```
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
```

I've changed to include quotes:-

```
@addTagHelper "*, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers"
```

Then I did a rebuild and its working again!?! All the 'asp-' attributes are also now highlighted as they were before. Why?!? Eh?!?

Stranger still, if I remove the quotes and rebuild, it still works! Well, at least until my colleagues get the file out of source control, they have to put the quotes back in!!

Figure that one out...

Comment: I checked in DOT NET 6.0 the quotes are not needed.

Answer (score 31):

For anyone meet the same problem, please check the location of the `_ViewImports.cshtml`, It must be in the same folder of your Views. For example, I have created a project that already have the `_ViewImports.cshtml` file in `Pages` folder, but I create and use my view files located in another folder, so ASP.NET can't find the `_ViewImports.cshtml` for our views.

With anyone have issue finding the project.json, you can right click at the project and choose Manage Nuget Packages then install the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers`.

Hope these advices can help everyone.

Comment: This was my problem. If you use Areas you need to make multiple dupes your _ViewImport file it seems. Add one to each Views folder

Comment: The `_ViewImports.cshtml` file affects all views in the same or descendant folders to where the `_ViewImports.cshtml` file is placed.

Comment: For me was the `environment` helper tag displayed all the enclosed content, regardless of the include value. So it looked like I had the typical double-value problem of Development and Production, when it was "simply" the helper tag was ignored, so its contents were always visible.

Comment: Using controllers and razor pages in a project, this saved my bacon, thanks

Answer (score 10):

For those w/ a ViewComponent inside a Razor Class Library (RCL), in addition to some of the other posted suggestions, 3 additional tweaks resolved my un-reachable Tag Helper for me:

1. The _ViewImports file should include an @using directive that points to your tag helper NAMESPACE (even though intellisense will think it's not needed)
2. The _ViewImports reference s/b to `@addTagHelper *, <DLL NAME>` - NOT necessarily the namespace name
3. Besides under the web app root directory, the _ViewImports file needs to also exist in the root of the RCL project - but is not needed w/in MVC "Areas" in the RCL nor any "Views" folder

Comment: "NOT necessarily the namespace name"  This is what did it for me. I have a .NET 6 project with underscores in the base namespace ("Something_Like_This"). When built, the DLL produced had spaces not underscores ("Something Like This.dll").  So I replaced the namespace with the DLL name, without .dll of course, and it worked.

Answer (score 8):

If you are experiencing the same problem when using Areas, add the `_ViewImports` file to the `Views` folder of your Area

Answer (score 4):

In your project.json dependencies, you are missing TagHelpers. Please add below line in dependencies section of project.json-

```
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers": "1.0.1",
```

On saving Project.json, VS2015 automatically restore packages.

If it doesn't worked then right click on project and click on Restore Packages option.

If this doesn't worked then try restoring using dotnet restore CLI command.

Comment: thanks, that's worked for new projects in a fresh solution. However it doesn't work for existing projects in existing solutions - whether they are v1.0.1 or have been upgraded to v1.1.0. I've tried other versions of the tag helper reference for the all projects but still no joy.

Comment: Do you receive any error? If it is problem with project.json then compare existing project.json vs fresh project.json.

Comment: @padigan Are you receiving any errors for existing project? what is the SDK version mentioned in your global.json?

Comment: Hi, its {
  "projects": [ "src", "test" ],
  "sdk": {
    "version": "1.0.0-preview2-003131"
  }
}

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with my application.
I had the reference to

```
@addTagHelper *,Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
```

In my `_ViewImports.cshtml` file, but this file was present inside of `~/Views/Home/` folder along with other views files, for the Views files in the same folder the Tag helper code was working correctly.

My `_Layout.cshtml` file was in the `~/Views/Shared/` folder. When I made a copy of the `_ViewImports.cshtml` file and moved the copy into the same folder with `_Layout.cshtml`, the Tag Helper code started to work correctly.

Then I moved the `_ViewImports.cshtml` to `~/Views/` and the Tag helper code started to work correctly for the views in both ~/Views/Home/ and ~/Views/Shared/ folder.

So the solution is to move the `_ViewImports.cshtml` file to the root of the Views folder (`~/Views/`) so it can be referenced by all the other Views files.

Comment: OMG this! ViewImports and ViewStart were both in a /Views/Shared directory. Moved them out to /Views director and voila.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and my _ViewImports.cshtml *was* in my Views folder.

For me, adding an extra line at the bottom of the _ViewImports.cshtml file did the trick:

```
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
@addTagHelper *, YourProjectNameHere
```

Answer (score 0):

I have this project.json for today:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "BundlerMinifier.Core": "2.4.337",
    "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore": "2.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.1.2",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.1.3",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers": "1.1.3",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing": "1.1.2",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.1.2",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.1.2",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.1.2",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.1.2",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.1.2",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.1.2",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.1.2",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.1.2",
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "type": "platform",
      "version": "1.1.1"
    },
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.1.0",
    //"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
    //"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGenerators.Mvc": "1.1.1",
    "Wallet.Core": "1.0.0-*"
  },

  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.1": {
      "imports": [
        "dnxcore50"
      ]
    }
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "runtimeOptions": {
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true
    }
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "**/*.cshtml",
      "appsettings.json",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "prepublish": [ "bower install", "dotnet bundle" ],
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that the tag helpers only helped for some views as @MayBeNextTime kindly informed us. Although, @Menace advises to add duplicates of the _ViewImports file to every Area you have views in, in order for the tag helpers to work for every view you have in your application, I found that by moving the _ViewImports file to the main application folder (right next to/or above Program.cs , Startup.cs , appsettings.json in your Solution Explorer) that you will achieve ubiquitous tag helpers' functionality without creating duplicate files in your app.

Check this out:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/layout?view=aspnetcore-2.2

It says:

A _ViewImports.cshtml file can be placed within any folder, in which case it will only be applied to pages or views within that folder and its subfolders.

Answer (score 0):

Here's good contender for the dumbest way to cause Tag Helpers to ignore you in disdain.  Try commenting out an individual HTML attribute...

```
<input id='@Model.InputId.Records[0].TenantId'
        class='class-1'
        @*class='class-2'   THIS WILL NEGATE THE asp-for ATTRIBUTE BELOW *@
        asp-for="@Model.Records[0].TenantId"
        type='text'
        placeholder='Required.' />
```

Comment: It does appear that you had 2 class attributes which is an error and perhaps you just needed `class='class-1 class-2'` for both classes

Answer (score 0):

If you already have that _ViewImports.cshtml file
If you have views in other folder structure like "WebHost/Features/MyFolder/Views/SampleView.cshtml" and not in WebHost/Views

Then move your _ViewImports.cshtml file in the project folder. Like WebHost/_ViewImports.cshtml

Now it should work for all views.

Answer (score 0):

In my case , I added viewimport.cshtml to Pages=>shared and it didn't work . I moved it to Pages and now it's available for all views .So it works.

Answer (score 0):

in my core 3.1 project, the problem turned out to be due to the connected Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word

```
<ItemGroup>
     <COMReference Include="Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word">
       <WrapperTool>tlbimp</WrapperTool>
       <VersionMinor>6</VersionMinor>
       <VersionMajor>8</VersionMajor>
       <Guid>00020905-0000-0000-c000-000000000046</Guid>
       <Lcid>0</Lcid>
       <Isolated>false</Isolated>
       <EmbedInteropTypes>true</EmbedInteropTypes>
<Private>true</Private>
     </COMReference>
   </ItemGroup>
```

after removing Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word everything worked, now I'm looking for something to replace Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word

Answer (score 0):

Some time there is an issue related to scope of `_ViewImports.cshtml` if we have multiple `_layout` files in our `Views` Folder.

You can add a `_ViewImports.cshtml` to any view folder, and the view engine applies the directives from both that file and the `Views/_ViewImports.cshtml` file. If you added an empty `Views/Home/_ViewImports.cshtml` file for the `Home` views, there would be no change because the `_ViewImports.cshtml` file is additive. Any `@addTagHelper` directives you add to the `Views/Home/_ViewImports.cshtml` file (that are not in the default `Views/_ViewImports.cshtml` file) would expose those Tag Helpers to views only in the `Home` folder.